# Restore default audio drivers in Ubuntu 16

Tags: drivers, 16.04, sound

I purchased a Windows laptop and replaced Windows with Ubuntu 16.

I experienced the low audio volume issue, where sound is only about 25% as loud in Ubuntu as it was in Windows, even with all settings at their max (with sound > 100% enabled as well). Since the other AskUbuntu solutions I found for this issue didn't work, I tried to install RealTek's linux codecs, as that is was is used in Windows.

Following the instructions in the `INSTALL` file, I ran `./configure` then `make` then `make install` and rebooted. Now I have no sound whatsoever and in the Sound Settings menu the "Default audio device" which appeared before under "Play sound through..." has been replaced with "Dummy output".

At this point I would be happy just to go back to the way things were before.

**How can I restore the defaults?**

I tried following https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting  but when I get to step 5 and run

```
sudo apt-get install linux-restricted-modules-`uname -r` linux-generic
```

The packages are not found.

> ```
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree       
> Reading state information... Done
> E: Unable to locate package linux-restricted-modules-4.4.0-47-generic
> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-restricted-modules-4.4.0-47-generic'
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-restricted-modules-4.4.0-47-generic'
> ```

I also tried following the advice from a thread on Ubuntu Forums saying to remove and reinstall these packages, then reboot. It didn't work:

```
  sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils
```

For reference, here's the output from `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"`:

> ```
> 00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
>   Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
>   Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
>   Memory at f1510000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
>   Capabilities: <access denied>
>   Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
>
> 00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
>   Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
> ```

Based on the output above I *think* my module name is `snd-hda-intel`. Under that assumption I tried to follow the Manual Installation section of the SoundTroubleshooting link above. It did not go well:

```
sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel
```

> modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:192
>   kmod_module_parse_depline() ctx=0x563319b75030
>   path=/lib/modules/4.4.0-47-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-codec.ko
>   error=No such file or directory modprobe: ERROR:
>   ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:192 kmod_module_parse_depline()
>   ctx=0x563319b75030
>   path=/lib/modules/4.4.0-47-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-codec.ko
>   error=No such file or directory modprobe: ERROR: could not insert
>   'snd_hda_intel': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see
>   dmesg)

However, someone just correctly pointed out that troubleshooting guide is very old anyway.

I just tried installing the DKMS driver as per https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS  and rebooted. Didn't seem to do anything.

I have no further ideas on how to fix this.

Comment: `lspci` should show the name of your sound card. Your first link `linux-restricted-extras` states it is mostly outdated as of 2012 so you can ignore those tips.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thanks; just made a related edit to the question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At LONG last I figured out how to reset everything:

```
sudo aptitude --purge-unused reinstall linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils linux-image-`uname -r` linux-ubuntu-modules-`uname -r` libasound2
```

If you encountered an error `E: Unable to locate package linux-modules-ubuntu-...`, this command can help:

```
sudo aptitude --purge-unused reinstall linux-modules-`uname -r` linux-modules-extra-`uname -r`
```

Comment: Command didn't work for me on 16.04

Comment: Neither for me ... cannot find linux-ubuntu-modules

Comment: @Rafael You have to include the -`uname -r` part (with backticks, like in my answer, but which can't appear in this comment due to syntax misinterpretation) to get the correct package name. But it's also possible that you just have a different problem. It would take a lot more information to know. You should start your own question if correcting the package name doesn't do the trick. Also make sure your sources are complete and up to date.

Comment: @Ligemer If you give a link to your question with the background on your problem, what you've tried, and system info then I will try to help you.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me as well after a long time searching for a solution (with slight modification from aptitude to apt)!

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sudo apt-get install pavucontrol linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils lightdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils lightdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.pulse*; ubuntu-support-status; sudo usermod -aG `cat /etc/group | grep -e '^pulse:' -e '^audio:' -e '^pulse-access:' -e '^pulse-rt:' -e '^video:' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's:,$::g'` `whoami`
```

From official documentation https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

Comment: This didn't work for me - I mentioned it in the original question

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Hack-R, I had your very same problem on Kubuntu 18.10, and you saved me with this last command that is not mentioned in the Troubleshooting page:

```
sudo aptitude --purge reinstall linux-modules-`uname -r` linux-modules-extra-`uname -r`
```

(I had the error of not found packages with the previous "standard" command).
**BUT**, for other users, I must note that as of december 2018, on Kubuntu but I also think on Ubuntu, the command worked **replacing --purge with --purge-unused** option (--purge itself is not anymore recognized). Also, you have to **reboot** the system to have effects applied.

I tried your same route, Hack-R, because it seemed to me that the audio quality on Kubuntu was worse than on Windows. Now I restored the system defaults, but how to achieve the "Realtek High definition audio" quality in the end?
I tried with the solution from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS
and, I would say to perceive better quality, but I'd not swear.

Best regards